# How do I reverse the loop?

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to do a KITT Led Scanner on the simulator at https://trinket.io/sense-hat. This is my code:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
s = SenseHat()
R = (255,0,0)
x = 0
y = 1
s.clear()



while True:
  First = s.set_pixel(x,4,R)
  Second = s.set_pixel(y,4,R)
  time.sleep(0.4)
  s.clear()
  x = x + 1
  y = y + 1
```

My question is, how do I reverse this motion and loop it once it reaches x = 0 and y = 1? Thank you!

Comment: it makes no sense to use the `y` variable .... use the `x` variable only, then use `Second = s.set_pixel(x+1,4,R)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable for the increment that can be switched from +1 to -1 depending on the position.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
s = SenseHat()
R = (255,0,0)
x = 0
y = 1
s.clear()

inc = 1

while True:
  First = s.set_pixel(x,4,R)
  Second = s.set_pixel(y,4,R)
  time.sleep(0.4)
  s.clear()
  x = x + inc
  y = y + inc
  if y == 7:
    inc = -1
  if x == 0:
    inc = 1
```